# Facebook comments, for each page

Tags: facebook

I installed facebook comments on my website. My website is a dynamic website and pages are like this www.example.com/page?id=54, www.example.com/page?id=67

If I post a comment in this page: www.site.com/page?id=54, it also appears in www.example.com/page?id=67. The comments are not unique for a page, but appear in every page. Why is that ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that FB ignores the `?query` part of the URL when retrieving comments.

What you could do: use some form of URl rewriting, so that your URLs are in the form http://www.example.com/page/id/54/ or similar (i.e., appearing to not use the `?id=something` query part). That way, the comments should load for each page separately.

Comment: Sample url for us to look at?

Comment: @DMCS: What do you mean? Please clarify.

Comment: @Sahan, your link to both http://www.example.com/page?id=67 and http://www.site.com/page?id=54 seem to be broken, can you post a real working link?

Comment: @DMCS: You are, I presume, not aware of the testing/example domain `example.com`, as specified in RFC2606? http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606#page-2 (note that `site.com` is an *actual*, real domain name) TLDR: example.com is an *example* domain.

Comment: Of course, but I had no idea you knew that since you didn't understand me asking @Sahan for a real URL to look at.

Comment: @DMCS: Ah, okay. Glad that's cleared up. Alas, I currently have no *real* URL on which you would see this.

Comment: But it was @Sahan's question.  I would highly doubt you would know their URL....unless somehow you and Sahan are the same.  Hence why I asked Sahan for the url.

Comment: @DMCS: I don't have any sockpuppets here, if that's what you're asking. But note that any @-replies addressed to the OP are automatically stripped out, hence my confusion (it wasn't clear whather you're replying to me or to the OP, as the system stripped out the @).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that worked for me. 
1- Copy this SDK from Facebook. Most probably you already did that.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function (d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=114215202075258";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

2- Then this

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-width="470" data-num-posts="3"></div>
```

3- The the solution line. Paste these lines of JS at the end. Make sure you do everything in the similar order as I have. It will work, no matter you have a ? in your URL.

```
<script>
$(".fb-comments").attr("data-href", window.location.href);
</script>
```