# How to add different facebook comments in different link in php?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to add Facebook comment box in each article by using following code. When I post comment to one article, it displays on all articles. I want to display different comments in different articles.

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div align="center"> <div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/sample" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"> </div> </div>
```

Comment: Use different values for `data-href` then. And add Open Graph meta tags to your pages if necessary – at least `og:url` to specify a unique URL for each of your articles.

Comment: I'm developing site for the online newspaper. There are many pages in the site. Will you kindly describe me what you are going to tell? I didn't get what you are saying.

Comment: @CBroe My problem is same as described in this link. But still unanswered... Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172122/facebook-comments-for-each-page